# Why is that when I enable packat, pyparsing returns different parse trees?

Tags: python, pyparsing

This is just a toy grammar to test backtracking:

```
from pyparsing import *
a = Literal("a")
b = Literal("b")
c = Literal("c")

abb = a + b + b
abc = a + b + c
aba = a + b + a

grammar = MatchFirst( [ abb.setDebug(), abc.setDebug(), aba.setDebug() ] )
grammar.parseString( "aba" )
```

With packrat **disabled**, the returned parse tree

```
['a', 'b', 'a']
```

With packrat **enabled**, I get

```
['a', 'b', 'b', 'a']
```

Why is this happening, in the last case ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in pyparsing. Corrected version has been checked into SVN.